# jquery show processing image on submit button click but hide if css error class exists in the form

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("#signUpFormSubmitButton").click(function(){
$('#processing').show();
});
```

This works fine.  When the submit button is clicked on the form, I show a processing spinning graphic.

I don't want to show the processing spinning graphic however, if there are errors on the form (form is not yet submitted).  I validate my form with jQuery as well and I add a "error" css class to the form input fields if there is an error.

I want to use the css error class as the flag for this.

I tried:

```
if (!$("#myForm input").hasClass("error") ) {
    $('#processing').show();
}
```

But did not work.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method and a simple selector

```
$("#signUpFormSubmitButton").click(function(){
    $('#processing').toggle($("#myForm input.error").length > 0);
});
```

> **toggle(showOrHide)**
>
> showOrHideA Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#myForm input").hasClass("error") ) {
      //your error code here }
else {
      //your loading image
$('#processing').show(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try counting the number of elements with the `.error` class:

```
if ($("#myForm input.error").length != 0)
{
    $('#processing').hide();
} else {
  // Show your spinner here
}
```